# cuda-gdb run >console permission denied OS X

Tags: macos, cuda, cuda-gdb

I'm trying to debug my CUDA code on OS X, and I need to run it in `>console` mode, since running it normally freezes the screen. But it keeps giving me the " permission denied " error. Is there a work around for this?.

Answer (score 2):

Please follow the steps outlined in "Setting Up the Debugger Environment" in [CUDA-GDB manual](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-gdb/index.html).

This problem is caused by the debugger requiring special permissions.